# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \iff A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove this theory. I would be happy if you could tell me if my proof is right, and where can I improve.

($\Leftarrow$) Assume $A = B$

Then $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$

Let there be $x \in A$

Then $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$

So $\{\{x\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)$

As such $\{\{x\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)$

And so $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$

Which means that $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$

---

($\Rightarrow$) Assume $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$

Then $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$

Let there be $x \in A$

Then $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$

So $\{\{x\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)$

As such $x \in B$

And so $A \subseteq B$

---

Let there be $x \in B$

Then $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(B)$

So $\{\{x\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)$

As such $x \in A$

And so $B \subseteq A$

And as such $A = B$

Q.E.D

Comment: You can improve by using the result of your last question: $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \iff \mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B) \iff A = B$

Comment: Yeah could be, but I've tried to make it without using other proofs, to make it less repeatable...

Answer (score 1):

While the theorem is true, your proof is imperfect. For the forward direction, you have not shown that $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$. You began with an element of $A$ and then constructed a specific element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, but you need to begin with an arbitary element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, in order to show the inclusion $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to add like that, although is what I've done wrong, or is it fine but just no the correct path that it should be by?

Comment: The step where make a logical error is saying that $\{\{x\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B)) \implies \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$. If you've already showed that $A=B \iff \mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B)$, then the easiest way to prove this result is just by using that. You shouldn't need to think about elements at all.